# Google docs script create a file in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, directory

I wrote a code to create a new file this file I put a page of my spreadsheet after I move it to another folder, the problem is on the move it. I've tried to makecopy function and addtofolder but neither worked all returned an error.

this is my code:

```
function pasta(){
  var fonte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder()
  var base = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Violino').next();
  var pasta1 = base.createFolder('Subfolder2');
  var destino = SpreadsheetApp.create("teste");
  var destinoF = DocsList.getFileById(destino.getId());
  fonte.copyTo(destino);
  destinoF.makeCopy("x",pasta1);
  destinoF.removeFromFolder(root);
  //Browser.msgBox(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your errors in the question too?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the problem by adding this line

var pasta2 = DocsList.getFolderById(pasta1.getId());

was a problem types, even both folder1 and folder2 varying types having the same name, they belong to different classes

My corrected and running code looked like this:

```
function pasta(){
  var fonte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder()
  var base = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Violino').next();
  var pasta1 = base.createFolder('Subfolder2');
  var pasta2 = DocsList.getFolderById(pasta1.getId());
  var destino = SpreadsheetApp.create("teste");
  var destinoF = DocsList.getFileById(destino.getId());
  fonte.copyTo(destino);
  destinoF.addToFolder(pasta2);
  destinoF.removeFromFolder(root); 
}
```